# My loop using charAt isn't working

Tags: java

I am in need of help for this loop. Basically what I am trying to do is run a loop. When the array String champs contains a character 'B' as it first letter it would display both the time and champ.

Could someone tell me what I've done wrong or why it isn't showing up? The output I receive from this is just "Time    Champs"

```
public static void displayTeam(short[] time, String[] champs){
    System.out.println("time     Champs");
    for(int a= 0; a < time.length; a++){
        char fletter=champs[a].charAt(0);
        if("B".equals(fletter)){
            System.out.println(time[a] + "     " + champs[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helps and contributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if("B".equals(fletter))
```

with this:

```
if('B' == fletter)
```

It's safe to use `==` for primitive values like `char`.

Since `fletter` is a `char`, what's happening with your code is rather complex. At first glance, one might wonder how this even compiles. What's going on is that `String.equals` takes an `Object` as an argument. Since `fletter` is a `char`, it gets [auto-boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) into a `Character` object. Then the String `"B"` checks to see if it's equal to its argument, notices that its argument isn't even a `String`, and returns `false`.

Comment: Ah thanks, makes sense. I don't know much about using char but did know a lot about using String. This helped heaps. :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

This isnt working because there is a difference between String and char.
the difference is one is a primitive value and one is not, and by using the double quotes instead of the single quotes you are making a String and not the char use single quotes :)

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out. I had no idea